# Setting fill to a variable based on data within SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Tags: r, sp, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm currently on the cusp of getting done what I want to get done - but having a slight problem with referring to my data from within R's `sp` `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` object. The issue is how `ggplot2` deals with spatial polygons, and factors that define or are mapped to them. I have my polygons, and in the `@data` element, I have the relevant data I'm interested in mapping/visualising, in a SpatialPolygonDataFrame called plotData. The following code;

```
p = ggplot(plotData, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id))

p + geom_polygon(fill=plotData@data$total,color='black')
```

yields an error about the number of elements within the aesthetic call:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1651526): colour, fill
```

I've tried a number of different ways of accessing these data - but am not able to actually figure out how to colour it based on anything within the @data element. The difference is something to do with how `ggplot2` treats polygons - (my data has only 2208 unique elements, and 2208 unique polys, not 1.6 million), but I can't seem to identify how this is put together.

Comment: Plotting sp polygon objects with ggplot isn't trivial and requires "fortifying" your data. See for edxample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174703/spatialpolygondataframe-plotting-using-ggplot#18174764 - suggest you either look into the `tmap` package or convert your sp class object to sf class with the sf package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okidokey.

So - it turns out that even though `ggmap2` can manage SpatialDataFrames, assigning values to it is pretty tricky. The issue I was having is a mismatch between each element of the polygon (so for a simple rectangular poly, there'd be 4 points), and the values associated with it. Fortifying the data as suggested by @Spacedman yields a basic data frame type (or using `broom::tidy` as suggested by internal package details), with groups or ID's assigned as expected.

What needs to happen is `tidy()` is called on the SpatialDataFrame - after which the data is joined using `left.join()` from base R. The concern is largely that this creates a great deal of redundant data - one polygon or statistical area needs only one record of the variable of interest - but the way the `aes()` function in ggplot2 works requires that each row has this value. Essentially for a polygon with 100 'corners', the same value needs to be stored 100 times.

After creating the SpatialPolygonDataFrame (which will soon if not already be deprecated by the `sf` package... but that's another story), it is fortified with `broom::tidy` as follows;

```
spdf = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(input variables)
tidy_spdf = tidy(spdf)
plotData = left_join(tidy_spdf,df_with_variables,by='id')
```

Then there is some simple renaming of columns in `plotData` for the sake of clarity, and the following line yields (a basic) version of what I wanted, where 'wmHrs' is the variable of interest.

```
p = ggplot() # Simply initialise an empty plot.
p + geom_polygon(data=plotData2, aes(fill=wmHrs,x=long,y=lat,group=Suburb)) # populate it!
```

Again - this is a solution, but perhaps not the cleanest one. It works, but from a programming perspective seems needlessly heavy on memory, particularly when your analysis grows! I'm marking this as the answer, and hopefully can inform others who are having the same stumbling blocks when starting in this sort of environment. Also - as @[Spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman) rightly pointed out [this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174703/spatialpolygondataframe-plotting-using-ggplot#18174764) was greatly informative - once you start figuring out how things are done (rather than asking why!).